# Rundeck won't start after patching (RHEL 7.8 latest patches added today)

Tags: rundeck

Here is my error.  Comes with a stacktrace but guessing this will be good enough.  This project worked fine before the patches.

[2020-07-28T10:20:45,262] WARN  services.ProjectManagerService - Discovered filesystem project RossNapOISOperations, importing...
[2020-07-28T10:20:45,824] ERROR boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():

- Field error in object 'rundeck.Project' on field 'description': rejected value [Build/Deploy/Maintenance on ROSS, NAP, and OIS Projects]; codes [rundeck.Project.description.matches.error.rundeck.Project.description,rundeck.Project.description.matches.error.description,rundeck.Project.description.matches.error.java.lang.String,rundeck.Project.description.matches.error,project.description.matches.error.rundeck.Project.description,project.description.matches.error.description,project.description.matches.error.java.lang.String,project.description.matches.error,rundeck.Project.description.matches.invalid.rundeck.Project.description,rundeck.Project.description.matches.invalid.description,rundeck.Project.description.matches.invalid.java.lang.String,rundeck.Project.description.matches.invalid,project.description.matches.invalid.rundeck.Project.description,project.description.matches.invalid.description,project.description.matches.invalid.java.lang.String,project.description.matches.invalid,matches.invalid.rundeck.Project.description,matches.invalid.description,matches.invalid.java.lang.String,matches.invalid]; arguments [description,class rundeck.Project,Build/Deploy/Maintenance on ROSS, NAP, and OIS Projects,^[a-zA-Z0-9\p{L}\p{M}\s.,()_-]+$]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] does not match the required pattern [{3}]]

Comment: Note that I see 2 patches for rundeck today:
rundeck-cli-1.3.1-1.noarch
rundeck-3.3.1.20200727-1.noarch

Comment: We removed all patches that were applied and that fixed the issue.  Is there an issue with one of the rundeck patches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's related to how Rundeck 3.3.X interprets the project description after an instance upgrade, a good way to solve it is back to rundeck 3.2.X, edit the projects descriptions without "special characters" and update to Rundeck 3.3.1 again. You can add your issue to [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6219) GitHub thread.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  I removed the /'s and the commas, reupdated, then got permission errors.  It appears that something has changed in permissions with the update as well.  I just went 777 on the project structure and that did the trick.  Not sweating security too much as this is internal use only...

Comment: You can even edit the descriptions inside projects file when you are trying to upgrade from filesystem projects mode